# Read from a file and return output in a vector

Tags: clojure

I'm just learning clojure and trying to read in a file and do something with the returned vector of results. In this instance I'm just trying to print it out.

Below is the code in question:

```
(defn read_file
  "Read in a file from the resources directory"
  [input]
  (with-open [rdr (reader input)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)])))

(defn -main []
  (println (read_file "resources/input.txt") ))
```

The println returns a "nil". What do I need to do to return "line"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is not very big, you can use [`slurp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp) to read the file content as a string, then split it with a specific delimiter (in this case `\n`).

```
(defn read-file [f]
  (-> (slurp f)
      (clojure.string/split-lines)))
```

Comment: you could use [clojure.string/split-lines](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/split-lines) instead

Answer (score 2):

`doseq` returns nil. It's supposed to be used when you're doing stuff in a `do` fashion on the elements of a sequence, so mostly side-effect stuff.

Try this:

```
(defn file->vec
  "Read in a file from the resources directory"
  [input]
  (with-open [rdr (reader input)]
    (into [] (line-seq rdr))))
```

But you shouldn't do this for big files, in those cases you don't want the whole file to sit in memory. For this reason, `slurp` is equally bad.

Comment: ...and sometimes even [`line-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) alone might be enough.